# Using the jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jbox

Can someone please try and clear up an issue I have when using the jquery plugin.

I have a script the uses jquery to perform a number of tasks such as:

Run an auto complete when users are entering data, works fine.
Run a script called jBox to call a popup window to display help screens, works fine.

And heres the BUT, if I have both of those in the same script, one works while the other does not.

If i call the plugins below, the auto complete works.

jquery-1.10.2.min.js

jquery-ui.js

but when I inclued the plugin below the popup does not.

jquery-3.2.0.js

jBox.js

I think my question is, which jquery plugin should I be using to get both the auto complete and the popup to work.

Is there an order which the jquery plugins should be in or am I using the wrong plugin's, or can I use just one plugin to do both jobs.

I have played around with the code by removing one or another but can;t get both to work on the same page.

Any help, advice would be great.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

i guess its not the issue with jquery but jq 1.10 is a stable one i gues the problem is with other two jq plugins they are conflicting so iguess use you should use no conflict 
to use it just assign something like this as a global var

```
$oldJq = noConflict();
```

then in the initialization section of the plugin initialize like

```
$oldJQ.DataTable({});
```

// just like this initialize your plugin(this once for datatable)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Interesting. I will look into that right now.